# Calling ListenableWorker not hitting startWork()

Tags: android, android-workmanager

I'm new to the work manager... I have a scenario in my application where I need to periodically backup the data to the server using a REST API. It seems that the work manager is a perfect solution for that (suggest me if there are any other :)).

From the docs, they are saying that ListenableWorker could meet my problem. So I have implemented it and called it using a OneTimeWorkRequest(just to test it PeriodicWorkRequest should be used in the proper case).

But the issue is that it is not triggering the worker :(.
Can anyone please help me to solve this issue. What I'm I missing??

```java
 Constraints constraints = new Constraints.Builder()
                .setRequiredNetworkType(NetworkType.CONNECTED)
                .build();

OneTimeWorkRequest request = new 
                OneTimeWorkRequest.Builder(SyncToServerWorker.class)
                        .setConstraints(constraints)
                        .build();

WorkManager.getInstance().enqueueUniqueWork("my-unique-name", 
                ExistingWorkPolicy.KEEP, request);
```

Worker class

```java
public abstract class SyncToServerWorker extends ListenableWorker {

    private Context context;
    public SyncToServerWorker(Context context, WorkerParameters params) {
        super(context, params);
        this.context = context;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ListenableFuture<Result> startWork() {
        return CallbackToFutureAdapter.getFuture(completer -> {

            BaseResponse.Callback callback = new BaseResponse.Callback() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess() {
                    completer.set(Result.success());

                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(String message) {
                    completer.setException(new Throwable(message));
                }
            };
            DataManager.getInstance(context).syncOfflineData(callback);
            return callback;
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that **Worker.doWork() is a synchronous call** - you are expected to do the entirety of your background work in a blocking fashion and finish it by the time the method exits. If you call an **asynchronous API in doWork() and return a Result**, your callback may not operate properly. If you find yourself in this situation, **consider using a ListenableWorker**.

Comment: Is your network constraint satisfied?  If so, please file a bug in the official issue tracker so the team can look at it.  If you have a sample app, that will help matters.

Comment: Hi, @SumirKodes I'm connected to a good network, so it is not the problem. Anyway, I'll post a bug in the official issue tracker.